# Cual seria el equivalente a un operador SQL IN Entity framework .NET?

Tags: .net

Cual seria el equivalente a un in, `select * from tabla_nombre where campo in ('valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3')`  esto pero en **entity framework**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] lista = { "valor 1", "valor 2", "valor 3" };
var resultado = from a in db.tabla_nombre  
                where lista.Contains(a.campo)
                select a;
```

O con Lambda

```
string[] lista = { "valor 1", "valor 2", "valor 3" };
var resultado = db.tabla_nombre.Where(a => lista.Contains(a.campo));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo